# Second JSON call not decoded

Tags: php, json

My program needs to do two json calls. The first one provides a list of ids which are then used, one at a time in a loop, to retrieve data with the second call.

The first call works great, but something is wrong in the second call. I know that I retrieved json data because I've echoed it out but I seem to die at the second json_decode because I see the echo "RETURNED:" and then "next" but I don't see the echo "DATA:". Do I have some sort of syntax error or did I foobar this in a more serious way?

```
<?php
$crl = curl_init();
$timeout = 30;
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.somesite.com/list?parm1=XXX&parm2=YYY&response_format=json");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
$ret = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
$data = json_decode($ret);
echo "<P>length:  $dlen </p>";
$somedata = $data->body->somedatas;
$count = 0;
foreach ( $somedata as $somedata ) 
{
  $id = $somedata->id;
  echo "<br />ID: " . $id;
  $command=""http://api.somesite.com/list2?id=$id&parm2=YYY&response_format=json";    
  $timeout = 30;
  echo "<br />Trying...";
  $crl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $command );
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
  $ret2 = curl_exec($crl);
  echo "<br />RETURNED=" . $ret2;
  curl_close($crl);
  echo "<br />next";
  $data2 = json_decode($ret2);
  echo "<br />DATA=" . $data2;
// more code follows...

}
echo "<br />done";
echo "<hr></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your file and fix it. Also, your `foreach` loop is changing itself, `($somedata as $somedata)`.

Comment: *COUGH COUGH $somedatas

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen [Does the `foreach()` really change](http://3v4l.org/PX6ro)?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen If there's a syntax error, the program won't run, so it will never call `error_reporting()`.

Comment: You have too many quotes here: `$command=""http:`. That must be a copying error, since the code wouldn't run at all like this.

Comment: Thanks guys. Obviously I edited out some proprietary info and a few of the syntax errors came from me changing things for the post. However, the real error was, indeed the foreach(). It now works. By the way, I don't yet have rights to vote up your answers but Sverri was first in with it.